# How to add Link Button at the corner of syncfusion's RibbonControlAdv

Tags: winforms, syncfusion

I'm using Syncfusion Essential Studio (Community License), and got stuck at the idea.

I want add a **link button** at the right corner of **RibbonControlAdv** like in Microsoft Office 2016 (Step 1-2)

[image: I want to add this]

Answer (score 1):

Currently RibbonControlAdv does not have support for adding button at the right corner. As a workaround, you can use LinkLabel and PopUpContainer(Syncfusion control) to provide this support. You could find the sample [here](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/174966/RIBBON~41486369581.ZIP)